# Getting variable undefined while trying to return a cards value in javascript

Tags: javascript, return-value

I am having trouble getting the value of the card to return an integer of 10 if the card string value is J or Q or K it should return the value of the card as 10 if Ace it should return as 1.
Here are is the code that I have written. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just want to return the proper value for each card within the rules of blackjack.

when trying to print to the console the values of the cards after using getValue(Z) and getValue(ZZ) I get undefined as the returned data.

The core of the issue is the getValue function doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```
  
const X = deck.cards[0].value
const Y = deck.cards[1].value
const Z = getValue(X)
const ZZ = getValue(Y)

console.log(X)
console.log(Y)
console.log(Z)
console.log(ZZ)






});

function getValue(){
  let cardvalue = deck.cards.value
  switch(cardvalue){
  case 'A':
    1
    break;
    case '2':
      2
      break;
      case '3':
        3
        break;
        case '4':
         4 
         break
         case '5':
           5
            break;
            case '6':
              6
              break;
              case '7':
                7
                break;
                case '8':
                  8
                  break;
                  case '9':
                  9  
                  break;
                    case '10':
                      10
                      break;
                      case 'J':
                        10
                        break
                      case 'Q':
                        10
                        break;
                        case 'K':
                          10
                        break;





   }
}
```

Link to my github blacjack project https://github.com/jesse6024/Blackjack

Comment: What is the core of the issue? Why do we need to see almost 250 lines of code? Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mre], along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work. Instead of `switch`, use [objects](/q/28330506/4642212).

Comment: Don't use increasing indentation in `case` blocks.

Comment: You need `return` statements in your `case` blocks, e.g. `case '5': return 5;`

Comment: I edited the question. I am now implementing the return keyword do each case statement. I Will update once finsihed.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you need to use `return` to return the card value. Just putting the value as a statement doesn't return it.

You can also simplify the code by combining all the cases that do the same thing. For all the numbered cards, the value is the same as the card's name, so use `parseInt()` to convert it. And all the royals return `10`, so combine them.

`cardvalue` should be the function parameter.

```js
function getValue(cardvalue) {
  switch (cardvalue) {
    case 'A':
      return 1
      break;

    case '2':
    case '3':
    case '4':
    case '5':
    case '6':
    case '7':
    case '8':
    case '9':
    case '10':
      return parseInt(cardvalue);
      break;

    case 'J':
    case 'Q':
    case 'K':
      return 10;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have implemented the function that you have written. Even with the return statements once the deal button is hit the console doesn't log the value of the cards. Here are some pics that show the implementation of the function written and the results they return for the first two cards within the shuffled deck of cards  https://ibb.co/8rhyJ5G
https://ibb.co/rctJ2dR

Comment: You need to make `cardvalue` the function parameter. `deck.cards` is an array, so `deck.cards.value` is `undefined`.

Comment: Barmar you are awesome. This has resolved my issue. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I made a card game for my friends to use during covid. Since various games value the cards differently, I put card values in data rather than code.

Like this:

```
// assign this depending on the game being played
let cardValues = { 'A': 1, '2': 2, '3': 3, '4': 4, '5': 5,
  '6': 6, '7': 7, '8': 8, '9': 9, '10': 10, 'J': 10, 'Q': 10, 'K': 10 };

// side benefit: this function is so simple you almost don't need it
function getValue() {
  return cardValues[cardValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function cardGameWinner(card1, card2) {
    const cardValues =  ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "JACK", "QUEEN", "KING", "ACE"]
    const card1Value = cardValues.indexOf(card1.value)
    const card2Value = cardValues.indexOf(card2.value)
    console.log("Card 1:", card1Value)
    console.log("Card 2:", card2Value)
}

card1Obj = {
    value: "2"
}

card2Obj = {
    value: "3"
}

cardGameWinner(card1Obj, card2Obj)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).